# Is it not possible to upgrade from "Windows 8 Basic" to "Windows 8 Enterprise"?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

We bought a new machine with "Windows 8" for our office (Vaio TAP 20) and we wanted to upgrade it to Windows Enterprise as we have a volume license of the same. Running "slui.exe" or "slui.exe 3" could not help us upgrade. We finally ended up running Windows 8 Enterprise setup.

Can someone verify this is indeed the method and that there is no other way to upgrade "Windows 8" (home or basic version) to "Windows 8 Enterprise" without a new setup?

Comment: No...No its not.  You also couldn't upgrade Windows 7 Professional to Enterprise.  The same was true for Vista.....

Comment: Hmm... I was wondering because Win 8 has this fancy upgrade tool built inside it that asks for new serial key and apparently allows you to upgrade. I also tried a Win 8 Pro key and that too was rejected.

Comment: It was rejected because you have to use Upgrade Anytime or whatever its called in Windows 8 to upgrade Windows 8 Core to Windows 8 Pro.  I have no idea what media your using but a Windows 8 Pro disk would have accepeted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this page on the MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj203353.aspx) You can only go from Windows 8 (Volume License) to Windows 8 Enterprise (Volume License).

The original install in your case was not a Volume License install so the upgrade is not possible.

Comment: I don't know if they just want to screw people over or if they just really want to confuse everyone - just for fun. I downloaded the Windows 8 Developer Preview last year and was told that you could upgrade when it became RTM. Then I go into the shop and everyone was saying no you can't upgrade and you can't do a fresh install either. This caused a great deal of confusion and so I just bought Windows 8 Pro. It worked. I was able to do a fresh install (and I even had the the option to upgrade instead of do a fresh install). But wtf? Why so much bs just to install some software? It's unnecessary

Comment: You have never been able to upgrade from a developer preview version of any microsoft OS, it was that way with Vista, and it was that way with Win 7, there is no reason to expect it would have been that way for 8. It is also the same [for 8.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/preview-faq) *"When you install subsequent editions of Windows 8.1 you'll be able to keep your personal files, but you'll need to reinstall your apps."* Which translates to "You will need to re-install windows for the release version". I would go back to who ever told you you could upgrade and correct them.

Comment: As to why, it makes it easier on them to do future updates. When they release a update they have to test it first, if they allowed people to upgrade the preview versions that would just be one more "method of instlling windows" that they must include in their tests. By making sure everyone starts the same it makes testing patches much easier.